# Trying to do provision

Tags: synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I have a  solution with SyncFramework. In some cases I need remove the changes that a child have to send to his father.

I was thought that I need to do a Deprovision in the Child, then delete the content of the table, and do a Provinsion.

This solve the problem?

This approach is similar to do this in SQL:

```
delete from Table;
delete from Table_tracking;
```

where `Table` is a table include in some scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're find deleting all the records on your table and the corresponding metadata, that should work.

alternatively, you can intercept the change dataset in the Changes Selected event and remove them from there.